# Counter in new column if a number or string matches from two data-frames R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I will try to give a best example for understanding. I have two data frames: **df1** and **df2**. In below dataframes, if a **Drug_Code_1** from **df1** matches with **Drug_Code_2** from **df2**, it should make a new column called **Drug_count** in **df1** and increment it by 1. If there are two different drugs for same Pat_ID then it should count as 2. Each **Drug_Code** has a unique **Drug_Names**. This should also merge the column values for each **Pat_ID** by comma ",". Below is an example of given df1, df2 and resultant df. Thanks

**df1**

```
Pat_ID       Date       Drug_Code     Drug_Names
1         2010-12-09     1.1.1          Alpha-21
1         2010-12-15     1.1.2          Alpha
1         2010-12-15     1.1.3          Beta
1         2010-12-15     1.1.3          Beta-29
2         2010-12-09     1.1.3          Beta
2         2010-12-17     1.1.4          Beta-32
1         2010-12-15     1.1.3          Beta
3         2011-02-09     1.2.1          Gamma-21
3         2011-04-25     1.2.2          Gamma
3         2011-04-25     1.3.1          Tango
```

**df2**

```
Drug_Code     Drug_Names
1.1.1           Alpha-21
1.1.2           Alpha
1.1.3           Beta
1.1.4           Beta-2
1.2.1           Gamma-21
1.2.2           Gamma
1.3.1           Tango
```

**Resultant df**

```
Pat_ID  Date                                 Drug_Code            Drug_Names           Count
1       2010-12-09, 2010-12-15, 2010-12-15   1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3  Alpha-21,Alpha, Beta    3                                         

2       2010-12-09, 2010-12-15               1.1.3, 1.2.1         Beta, Gamma-21          2            

3       2011-02-09, 2011-04-25               1.2.1, 1.2.2         Gamma-21, Gamma         2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Pat_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3),
  Date = c("2010-12-09", "2010-12-15", "2010-12-15", "2010-12-15", "2010-12-09",
           "2010-12-17", "2010-12-15", "2011-02-09", "2011-04-25", "2011-04-25"),
  Drug_Code = c("1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", "1.1.3", "1.1.3", "1.1.4", "1.1.3", "1.2.1",
                "1.2.2", "1.3.1"),
  Drug_Names = c("Alpha-21", "Alpha", "Beta", "Beta-29", "Beta", "Beta-32", "Beta",
                 "Gamma-21", "Gamma", "Tango")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Drug_Code = c("1.1.1", "1.1.2", "1.1.3", "1.1.4", "1.2.1", "1.2.2", "1.3.1"),
  Drug_Names = c("Alpha-21", "Alpha", "Beta", "Beta-2", "Gamma-21", "Gamma", "Tango")
)
library(dplyr)

merged_df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "Drug_Code")

result_df <- merged_df %>%
  group_by(Pat_ID) %>%
  summarise(
    Date = paste(Date, collapse = ", "),
    Drug_Code = paste(Drug_Code, collapse = ", "),
    Drug_Names = paste(`Drug_Names.x`, collapse = ", "),  # Updated column name
    Count = n_distinct(Drug_Code)
  )

print(result_df)
```

output would be:

```
  Pat_ID Date                                         Drug_Code Drug_Names Count
   <dbl> <chr>                                        <chr>     <chr>      <int>
1      1 2010-12-09, 2010-12-15, 2010-12-15, 2010-12~ 1.1.1, 1~ Alpha-21,~     1
2      2 2010-12-09, 2010-12-17                       1.1.3, 1~ Beta, Bet~     1
3      3 2011-02-09, 2011-04-25, 2011-04-25           1.2.1, 1~ Gamma-21,~     1
```

Comment: Count for all 3 is 1 in the solution.  You need to count before you collapse the Drug Code.  You can also simplify the `paste` statements using `across`